# Android Sorting a multidimensional object or array of int

Tags: android, sorting, object, multidimensional-array, int

Is there a way to sort a multidimensional Object?

```
Object[][] datetable= new Object[2][2];

    datetable[0][0] = 2;
    datetable[0][1] = "Name2";
    datetable[1][0] = 1;
    datetable[1][1] = "Name1";
```

If not, how would I sort a multidimensional int array?

```
int[][] numtable= new int[2][2];

    numtable[0][0] = 2;
    numtable[0][1] = 20;
    numtable[1][0] = 1;
    numtable[1][1] = 10;
```

I would like to sort it using the first set of numbers (numbtable[x] or datetable[x])
I can get a multidimensional string to sort no problem, but these I have trouble with.

Comment: is there a reason you're using multidimentional arrays? it looks like you're simply using the 1,2,... values as keys to the real data value, in which case why not use either a `Map<Integer, String>` or a simple `List<String>` and use `Collections.sort(List)` or your own `Comparator` in the `TreeMap` definition. What are you using the arrays for? It's not clear to me from your data what you're trying to do.

Comment: The size of the actual array will be [5][12], full of both int's and Strings... if I can't get it to work, I'll have to make two separate arrays, one for int and one for string... but I don't know how to sort and int array

Answer (score 0):

Sorting arrays of int's is done through using Integer objects and using a comparator, similar to hotveryspicy's answer, as here:

```
Integer[][] numtable = new Integer[2][2];
numtable[0][0] = 2;
numtable[0][1] = 20;
numtable[1][0] = 1;
numtable[1][1] = 10;

Arrays.sort(numtable, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer[] int1, Integer[] int2) {
        return int1[0].compareTo(int2[0]);
    }

});
```

However, from your comments, you seem to indicate you'll have a 5x12 array of objects interspersed with strings and ints which don't relate to each other (the sorting loses any connection between your items, which is what makes me think this), which you seem to be merging into one multidimensional array instead of separate lists (which is how i'd probably go).

if you do convert to a List of ints/strings, then use the following to sort them, in this case, i show the int version:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myList.add(2);
myList.add(1);
Collections.sort(myList);
System.out.println("myList is: " + myList);
```

Comment: Thanks. The 5x12 array would be used to hold data(12) for 5 items. From the sources I've searched through, Objects are the only array that can hold both int and string but are not sortable. So I will be using 2 separate arrays. A 5x8 for int and 5x4 for string while using the first variables to sort.